# setting up ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Guys I'm new to angular and trying to figure out how to implement a module called ngDialog so that I can have a pop up appear with angular data ect. Right now, I have my controller:

```
var oflApp = angular.module('oflApp', ['ngDialog']);
oflApp.controller('oflClassCtrl', function ($scope,ngDialog) {
$scope.classes = [
{"class": "ENGLISH I: INTRO TO LITERATURE AND COMPOSITION Sem 2", "href": "../courses/english.php#p1"}, ect
}];
$scope.clickToOpen = function(index){
       $scope.selectedClass= $scope.classes[index];
       ngDialog.open({template: '../inc/popUp.html'});
    };
});
```

And html:

```
<table ng-controller="oflClassCtrl">
…
<tr ng-repeat = "selectedClass in classes | filter:searchTxt">
        <td><a  ng-click="clickToOpen($index)">{{selectedClass.class}}</a></td>
```

of course i've added the scripts underneath my angular scripts but is there anything else i need for this to work? I'm not sure what's going on but the pop will not show up on click so im sure something is wrong. What am I doing wrong? Thanks friends.

edit: I refactored my js because i was bored and read about doing it this way, but still doesn't work

```
(function(){



angular.module('oflApp', ['ngDialog'])
.controller('oflClassCtrl', oflClassCtrl)

function oflClassCtrl($scope,ngDialog) {
    // $http.get('../courses/coursedata.json');
    $scope.clickToOpen = function(index){
    $scope.selectedClass= $scope.classes[index];
    ngDialog.open({template: '../inc/popUp.html'});
    };


  $scope.classes = [
{"class": "ENGLISH I: INTRO TO LITERATURE AND COMPOSITION Sem 2", "href": "../courses/english.php#p1"},ect..
 ];




} //cntrler

})();
```

Comment: Your code looks pretty good. Check the network tab of your dev tools to see if the `../inc/popUp.html` template is being loaded correctly? The relative URL you're using might be confusing Angular.

Comment: So What is The Error ? provide the error so that we can help you as much as we can @codemonkey

Comment: so im getting: ngDialog.min.css:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL . But the main thing is nothing is happening when i click on the ng-repeat items. It will not bring up a pop up. SO maybe the open function or something in the click function is off.

Comment: im also getting a XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/inc/popUp.html". when i click on the repeats but nothings popping up.

Comment: Maybe because of your css styling that makes the model does not display (hidden away from your eyes). You can check on your DOM when you click on the link whether there is new piece of DOM append to your orginal DOM. I test your code and it is working fine. Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/fxnj2waz/

Comment: yes i can see it appending the dom when i click a link but how do i fix it? Is there something wrong with my includes or why is the css not rendering?